# Dijkstras algorithm with each edge having cost as well as distance

Tags: c, graph-algorithm

I have to modify dijikstras algorithm with each edge having two values-one as distance and other as cost.I have to find the most efficient way from source to destination.
Can anyone suggest a way for comparing the edges based on both the factors??
Thankyou

Comment: Define most efficient. I think is 99% of the problem.

Comment: You have to be more specific. In most cases distance and cost are considered correlated metrics.

Comment: Exactly. The question is what you are minimizing. If not just distance, then what? We cant tell you, it really depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Efficiency is defined as useful work produced divided by amount spent to do the work. So: determine how to compute work produced, determine how to compute amount spent, and write the algorithm that maximizes work divided by amount spent. How you do that is up to you; how should we know what your "cost" and "distance" mean in relation to your work produced?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply these factors? Or sum them up or build a custom function f(distance, cost) -> value which returns reasonable values

Comment: reasonable value based on what??

Comment: @user3098026: based on what you want to do. You need to provide more details for us to be more specific. For example, why do you have two metrics per edge? Are they completely independent? Which metric will you be trying to minimize?

Comment: Based on your values for costs or distance. I would try a simple multiplication => f(distance, cost) = distance * cost.

Comment: @Adrian: that would assume that the "cost" is in fact the cost per unit of distance. That may not be true. Unless the OP tells us what exactly they want to do, we will all be taking shots in the dark...

Comment: @Adrian: in fact, in many common cases you cannot minimize both. For example, when selecting transportation paths airplanes are usually the most expensive option, while ships are cheaper but take significantly more time, and often have to cover more distance since a direct path is not always possible.

Comment: @thkala what you say is correct. I was just taking a shot in the dark based on  my experienced with CS profs and their exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Use `f(cost,distance)` where `f` is a weight function which you use as your new cost and use the algorithm as before.

Comment: Thanx for answering but based on what factors should i do calculation in weight function??